# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^3}{(y+z)^3}-\frac{y^3z^3}{(x^2+yz)^3}\right)\ge 0$ for $x, y, z > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers,How prove this inequality
> $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{x^3}{(y+z)^3}-\dfrac{y^3z^3}{(x^2+yz)^3}\right)\ge 0$$

My idea want use the SOS methods, but it is very ugly, is there any nicer method? Thank you

Example problems using the SOS method at: http://ineqkhoinguyen.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/ren-luyen-sos.pdf

Comment: Can you explain what $\sum_{cyc}$ means?

Comment: such $\sum_{cyc}a=a+b+c,\sum_{cyc}a^2b=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a,\cdots$

Comment: It's not clear why that link is there, since it doesn't clarify what the SOS method is.

Comment: I know only two articles in English that describe SOS (sum of squares), here is one by [David Arthur](https://sites.google.com/site/imocanada/2009-summer-camp)  and here is one by [Pham Kim Hung](http://ohkawa.cc.it-hiroshima.ac.jp/AoPS.pdf/Sum%20Of%20Squares%20-%20Pham%20Kim%20Hung.PDF) (the second link is direct link to PDF, the first isn't).

Answer (score 1):

*Remarks*: Here is a computer proof. One may verify each step in this proof using computer. It is not easy to verify it by hand.

If $x = y = z$, clearly the inequality is true.

In the following, assume that $(x-y)^2 + (y - z)^2 + (z - x)^2 \ne 0$.

By AM-GM, we have $x + y + z > 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}$
and $xy + yz + zx > 3\sqrt[3]{xy \cdot yz \cdot zx}$ which results in
$$(x + y + z)(xy + yz + zx) - 9xyz > 0. \tag{1}$$

We have (degree three Schur inequality)
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} x(x - y)(x - z) > 0. \tag{2}$$

Since the desired inequality is homogeneous,
assume that $xyz = 1$.

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx$.

The inequality is written as
\begin{align*}
f(p, q) &:= -3\,{p}^{3}{q}^{12}+ \left( 9\,{p}^{5}+9\,{p}^{2} \right) {q}^{11}+
 \left( -6\,{p}^{7}+30\,{p}^{4}-9\,p \right) {q}^{10}\\
 &\qquad + \left( {p}^{9}-
 162\,{p}^{6}-213\,{p}^{3}+4 \right) {q}^{9}\\
 &\qquad + \left( 135\,{p}^{8}+351\,
 {p}^{5}+369\,{p}^{2} \right) {q}^{8}\\
 &\qquad + \left( -36\,{p}^{10}+702\,{p}^{7
 }+855\,{p}^{4}-279\,p \right) {q}^{7}\\
 &\qquad + \left( 3\,{p}^{12}-930\,{p}^{9}
 -4695\,{p}^{6}-3462\,{p}^{3}+93 \right) {q}^{6}\\
 &\qquad + \left( 351\,{p}^{11}+
 1728\,{p}^{8}+6795\,{p}^{5}+4374\,{p}^{2} \right) {q}^{5}\\
 &\qquad + \left( -54
 \,{p}^{13}+1359\,{p}^{10}+9288\,{p}^{7}+2169\,{p}^{4}-2610\,p \right) 
 {q}^{4}\\
 &\qquad + \left( 3\,{p}^{15}-955\,{p}^{12}-11898\,{p}^{9}-36483\,{p}^{6
 }-14995\,{p}^{3}+696 \right) {q}^{3}\\
&\qquad + \left( 225\,{p}^{14}+4224\,{p}^{
  11}+25686\,{p}^{8}+52317\,{p}^{5}+16068\,{p}^{2} \right) {q}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +
 \left( -24\,{p}^{16}-618\,{p}^{13}-5808\,{p}^{10}-23538\,{p}^{7}-
 35670\,{p}^{4}-7824\,p \right) q\\
 &\qquad +{p}^{18}+33\,{p}^{15}+426\,{p}^{12}+
 2677\,{p}^{9}+8163\,{p}^{6}+9912\,{p}^{3}+1728\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}

We use the approach introduced in [this](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/616532245) (in Chinese).

Let
\begin{align*}
 a &= p^3 - 4pq + 9r = p^3 - 4pq + 9, \\
 b &= pq - 9r = pq - 9, \\
 c &= \frac{p^3}{r}(-4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2})\\
 &= {p}^{3} \left( -4\,{p}^{3} + {p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pq-4\,{q}^{3}-27 \right) .
\end{align*}
From (1) and (2), we have $a, b > 0$.
We have $c \ge 0$ since
$ (x - y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2 = -4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2}$.)

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\left( {p}^{3}-4\,pq+9 \right) ^{11} \left( pq-9 \right) ^{16}{p}^{9}\cdot f(p, q)\\
  ={}& a^7b^{19}(1062365a^2 - 37473ab + 7978b^2) + g(a, b, c)
\end{align*}
where
$g(a, b, c)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.

Thus, $f(p, q) \ge 0$.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong! Try $y+z=0$.

For positive variables your inequality is true but not so easy (at lest my proof is very ugly)

and I think SOS does not help here.